# Is it possible to find the object property name

Tags: groovy

I am looking for solution to find the property name of given object in a mother object. I tried iterate through hall the mother object compare with objects with is operator, but I can get the property name from the mother class.

Pseudo Example:

```
Class Boo {
   List<B> bb_property = []
}
Class Foo {
   List<A> a_property = []
   List<B> b_property = []
   Boo boo = new Boo()
}

Foo foo = new Foo()

List<A> randomname = foo.a_property

String propertyname = foo.findPropertyNameOf(randomname) //this is here where the magic should happen
assert propertyname == "a_property"


List<A> someOtherRandomName = foo.boo.bb_property

propertyname = foo.findPropertyNameOf(someOtherRandomName) //this is here where the magic should happen
assert propertyname == "bb_property"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy provides a number of ways for you to get the properties on an object.  One easy way is the `properties` method which returns a map of name to value.

That can be seen here:
[Groovy property iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477706/groovy-property-iteration)

And you can then compare for reference equality (which I assume is what you'd want as opposed to value equality):
[How can I perform a reference equals in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417265/how-can-i-perform-a-reference-equals-in-groovy)

You do have to watch our for cycles through, especially with properties such as `class` which will definitely have references to itself.

Putting that altogether with just simple avoidance of class/metaClass and *not* full cycle prevention you can do it as follows:

```
Object.metaClass.findPropertyNameOf = { v ->
   delegate.properties.collect { pn, pv ->
      pv.is(v) ? pn : (pn in ["class", "metaClass"] ? null : pv.findPropertyNameOf(v))
   }.find { it != null }
}
```